# Change background color with a list color

Tags: android

I couldn't find any informations about changed background color when I click on it, and change the background of all my activity/fragments with the clicked color.

I have this for the moment for the model:

```
 public static ColorHandler getInstanceColor(){

        return mInstanceColor;

    }

    public ColorHandler(Context context){
        mInstanceColor=this;
        colorPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(mypreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (colorPreferences.contains("colorPref")){
            currentColor = (String) colorPreferences.getAll().get("colorPref");
        }
        else{
            currentColor = Red;
        }
    }


    public String getColor(){

        return currentColor;

    }

    public void setColor(String colory){

        //currentColor= colory;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = colorPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.putString("colorPref",colory);
        editor.commit();
```

For the controller:

```
private ListView listColor;
private String[] mStrings = {"BlueLight", "BlueDark", "GreenLigth", "GreenDark", "OrangeLigth", "OrangeDark","PinkLigth","PinkDark","GrayLigth","GrayDark","RedLigth","RedDark","HiddenLigth","HiddenDark"};
private ColorHandler choiceColor;

  choiceColor = new ColorHandler(getActivity());

    listColor.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            String colory = (String) (listColor.getItemAtPosition(i));

            choiceColor.setColor(colory);
            String colorDesigned = (String)ColorHandler.getInstanceColor().getColor();
            LinearLayout ll;
            ll = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.mon_layout);
            ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ColorHandler.getInstanceColor().getColor(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

And I want to change the background with these color in colors.xml:

```
<color name="BlueLight">#5C9EED</color>
<color name="BlueDark">#4A8CDB</color>
<color name="GreenLigth">#42CC6F</color>
<color name="GreenDark">#3BB75D</color>
<color name="OrangeLigth">#FAB154</color>
<color name="OrangeDark">#F49B42</color>
<color name="PinkLigth">#EC87C0</color>
<color name="PinkDark">#D770AD</color>
<color name="GrayLigth">#606873</color>
<color name="GrayDark">#3E464F</color>
<color name="RedLigth">#ED5F55</color>
<color name="RedDark">#D84C43</color>
<color name="HiddenLigth">#A5ADB8</color>
<color name="HiddenDark">#838992</color>
```

Thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed the color string in the following line

```
ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor());
```

You need to put the selected color string in the parseColor. So try by replacing the line with the following

```
ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colorDesigned ));
```